# How can computer memory remember after the computer runs out of battery?

Tags: memory-hardware

According to my fragile knowledge of computer hardware the way computers store information is by electric circuits. If there is current the bit is 1 if there isnt its 0. My question is after a computer runs out of battery the memory stil holds all of the information, how? Wont it be the case that all the bits are 0?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-volatile_random-access_memory

Answer (score 1):

There’s permanent storage that doesn’t need any power and lasts forever.

Your computer likely has a tiny battery for important things like clock time which should last for a very long time.

Your computer probably has code that dumps all memory contents to permanent storage just before the battery runs out and reads it back when there is enough battery life.